# How to store user input as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to design a simple companion interface for a board game I am creating. How do you request user input, and then update a variable with the new input and display the new result? ie. "What number did you roll?" -> "You are now on [this] space."

Sorry, I am very new to coding... Here is the closest I've got

```
<var space = 1>


<button onclick="mySpaceNumber()">Die Roll</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function mySpaceNumber() {
var dieroll = prompt("What did you roll?", "Enter Value");
if (dieroll != null) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"You are now on " + function mySpace  ;

function mySpace(){
    'space'= 'space'+ 'dieroll'
    space
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

`if (dieroll != null) {` - This will always be NOT null if something isn't entered. Reason being is that it is UNDEFINED, rather than NULL. These are two different things. Null is an actual value. When a variable has been declared, but no value has been given to it then it becomes undefined.
With that said, I would make this line `if (dieroll !== "undefined)"`

Regarding `'space'= 'space'+ 'dieroll'`
I would not put any apostraphe's in the variable's NAME, that is something you want to do when you declare a string.

Regarding this: You will want to put your code on one line.
From: 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"You are now on " + function mySpace  ;
To:
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You are now on " + mySpace();`

The variable `space` is undefined, you have not initialized it or given it a value. To do that we need to add this in `var space=0;`

Lastly, I don't see your HTML so I'm not sure what element the variable space is supposed to reference. If it's some other box or something you can remove the `var space=0;` and get the value by selecting the element you need it from. Without knowing what that would be or what your html looks like I can't speculate further.

With all that said, here is where we are.

```
function mySpaceNumber() {
var dieroll = prompt("What did you roll?", "Enter Value");
if (dieroll !== "undefined") {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You are now on " + mySpace();
function mySpace(){
    var space=0;
    space = space + dieroll;
    return space
}
}
}
```

Then onto the HTML
 This is not valid.

---

### Code Snippet

```js
function mySpaceNumber() {
 var dieroll = prompt("What did you roll?", "Enter Value");
  if (dieroll !== "undefined") {
  document.getElementById("roll").value = dieroll;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You are now on " + mySpace();


 }
   function mySpace(){
    result = getSpace();
   return result;
   }
   function getSpace(){
    gs1 = +document.getElementById('quantity').value + +document.getElementById('roll').value
    return gs1;
   }
   document.getElementById('quantity').value = +document.getElementById('quantity').value + +document.getElementById('roll').value
}

function resetSpace(){
document.getElementById('quantity').value = '1';
}
```

```html
<div>Roll:
<input type="number" id="roll" name="roll" style="width: 50px;" />
Current Space:
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" style="width: 50px;" />
</div>

<button onclick="mySpaceNumber()">Die Roll</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetSpace()">reset</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I'm looking for thanks! My only problem now is, when you run the function mySpaceNumber again it just returns what value you just entered, not the sum of the new value plus the previous value

Comment: Sure, I added a code snippet so you can see how to do that. It's a little messy but it works.